# Magento 1.8 - Remove Order Review from OnePage Checkout

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm trying to skip the order review stage of the onepage checkout process, so once a payment method has been selected it goes straight to the card processing.

There are no terms and conditions to agree to in the checkout.

I've tried to follow this guide:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8232

However I am not sure how to create the observer, or where it goes.

Has anyone got a full solution to this? I've hit a dead end.

Comment: check this one : http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/17/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-shipping-method-step/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **basics idea** of **removing any step from checkout** is
 - Change javascript and HTML to remove the step display
 - Set **default values in Quote object** for the step removed, so that **checkout process goes smoothly**. 
For easy reference i have **removed the payment** method step from **onepage checkout**.

**Step1: Onepage Block**

- First we need to override the Onepage.php block, so that we can
  change the steps array. So to override the block
  **Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage** open your module’s config.xml file and
  put inside the blocks tag, below code

  ```
  <checkout>
         <rewrite>
                   <onepage>Excellence_Remove_Block_Onepage</onepage>
           </rewrite>
  </checkout>
  ```

  So the core block Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage has been overridden by Excellence_Remove_Block_Onepage block. In the code in this block is

  ```
      if (!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
          $steps['login'] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData('login');
      }

      $stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'payment', 'review');

      foreach ($stepCodes as $step) {
          $steps[$step] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData($step);
      }
      return $steps;
  }
  ```

  }

Here i have simple removed the ‘shipping_methods’ step.

**Step2:** **pHTML and Javscript**
Here we need to include **our custom javascript file** for the checkout, since we will make changes to the **onepage.phtml file.** We will include the **javascript file in onepage.phtml**. Using the layout file, we will override the **default phtml file to our modules phtml file**.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/removecheckout.js') ?>"></script>
```

and also change the javsacript code
**From**

```
var checkout = new Checkout(accordion,{
```

**to**

```
var checkout = new Excellence(accordion,{
```

Next **we need to create the Excellence javascript class in the removecheckout.js**

```
var Excellence = Class.create(Checkout, {
    initialize: function($super,accordion, urls){
        $super(accordion, urls);
        //New Code Addded
        this.steps = ['login','billing', 'shipping', 'payment', 'review'];
    }
});
```

The full source code for doing the above is found in the module files.

**Step3: Onepage Controller**
The default **OnepageController.php is override** so that we can change to functions. **The saveBillingAction() and saveShippingAction()**. The source code is given below

```
public function saveBillingAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            //            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
            //            $data = $this->_filterPostData($postData);
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
            $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);

            if (isset($data['email'])) {
                $data['email'] = trim($data['email']);
            }
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);

            if (!isset($result['error'])) {

                $method = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
                $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($method);

                if (!isset($result['error'])) {

                    if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
                        $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                        $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'payment-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                        );
                    } elseif (isset($data['use_for_shipping']) && $data['use_for_shipping'] == 1) {
                        $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                        $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'payment-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                        );

                        $result['allow_sections'] = array('shipping');
                        $result['duplicateBillingInfo'] = 'true';
                    } else {
                        $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping';
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }

    public function saveShippingAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping', array());
            $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_address_id', false);
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShipping($data, $customerAddressId);

            if (!isset($result['error'])) {
                $method = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
                $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($method);

                if (!isset($result['error'])) {

                    $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'payment-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                    );
                }
            }
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }
```

This is all that is required to remove the shipping step. By using above example you can also remove review step